# Contact page redirect issue

Tags: php, html, contacts

For some reason my contact page won't relocate to thanks.html. It just stays at the contact page and the contact form disappears.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$errors = array();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Name, email, and message are required.';
} else {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valad email address.';
    }
}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    mail('joe@mydomain.com', 'Contact Form' ,'$message', 'From: ' . $email);
    header('Location: thanks.html');
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Here is my code from the form as well.

```
<?php
if (empty($errors) === false) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach($errors as $error) {
    echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
}
echo '<ul>';


}
?>




</div>
<div id="content">






<form action="" method="post">

<p>
<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) {            echo              'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?> />
</p>
<p>
<label for="email">Email:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?>/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="message" id="message"><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) { echo  strip_tags($_POST['message']), ''; } ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" />
</p>


</form>







</div>
```

Anyone have a quick fix for this? It's driving me crazy. I've been trying different variations of these lines in the code above but nothing is working...

```
if (empty($errors) === true) {
mail('joe@mydomain.com', 'Contact Form' ,'$message', 'From: ' . $email);
header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();
```

Comment: according to your logic, the control will never go to this part of the code: 
if (empty($errors) === true) { since you are populating $errors in both the cases above this line. so the redirection will never take place.

Comment: I'm receiving the emails in the 'mail' line though..?

Comment: in that case there might be some issues with your header() function call.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are close,

**SOLUTION**

give it a complete address to redirect after

**if its doing email then just change your**

---

header('Location: thanks.html');

to

header('Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.html');

Also replace

empty($name) === true to empty($name)

you dont need to specify for true, it will take by default

---

Comment: add me on skype : zainzain185, lets do this live

Comment: also remove exit(); you dont need that

Answer (score 0):

as the [PHP manual page for header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) points out, you should really use full URLs to redirect:

```
Note: HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:
```

you can also use `javascript` to redirect to thanks page as follows:

```
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    mail('joe@mydomain.com', 'Contact Form' ,'$message', 'From: ' . $email);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
         , 'window.location.replace('thanks page complete url');'
         , '</script>'; 
}
```

Comment: If you mean using http://www.sitename.com/folder/thanks.html , that doesn't work.

Comment: suggested another way of redirection using javascript